# Intel Edison with mini breakout board does not boot

Tags: intel-edison

I have an Intel Edison with the mini breakout board.  I have connected a USB cable to the J3 connector and I see the serial device, FT232R USB UART, on my computer.  But when I try to connect using `screen /dev/tty.usbserial-A502LTL3 115200 -L` I get a blank screen.  It seems like the Edison is not on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to connect a USB cable to the J16 connector as well.  The J16 USB port provides power to the Edison board.  The other one, J3, is only for serial access - it does not power the board.